Why is so much of likelihood theory focused on solving the score function equation?
When I first learnt about maximum likelihood estimation, I was told that I should check that the solution of $\frac{d}{d\theta}\text{log}(L(\theta;x_1,...,x_n)) = 0$ was really the maximum likelihood estimator; this meant checking that it was really a maximum, which amounted to checking the second derivative and also checking the behaviour of the log-likelihood at the boundaries of the parameter space.
However, after a while, professors and textbooks just started focusing only on solving $\frac{d}{d\theta}\text{log}(L(\theta;x_1,...,x_n)) = 0$. We didn't need to check anything else, we just needed to solve that equation. So why don't we need to check that the solution of $\frac{d}{d\theta}\text{log}(L(\theta;x_1,...,x_n)) = 0$ is really the maximum likelihood estimator? When do we need to check?

Maybe it's also true that for many standard cases these auxiliary requirements are true, so we get lazy and don't bother checking them.

You do not need the second order condition when the likelihood is log-concave, which is the case for exponential families.

@Xi'an do we still need to check if anything strange happens at the boundaries of the parameter space?

The continuous version of the German Tank Problem, i.e. where $X \sim U[0,\theta]$, is a classic example where just looking for a solution to $\frac{d}{d\theta}\text{log}(L(\theta;x_1,...,x_n)) = 0$ does not work, and it is easy enough to invent more complicated examples.  If there are multiple zeros or no zeros or indicator functions, then you may want to take more care.

This is true beyond statistics: either 1) we are willing to assume convexity, and then First Order Optimality Conditions do the trick (which in full generality handles bound constraints) or 2) we aren't, and then all bets are off. (Even a negative definite Hessian only commits us to a local optimum).

While it is in general possible for the loglikelihood to have many stationary points, there are a lot of problems where we already know that there is only one (many glms; the Cox proportional hazards model; many accelerated failure models). There are other problems where we know how to find good starting values that ensure we end up at the right stationary point (maximum likelihood for the Cauchy, where starting optimisation at the median is reliable).
One  contributing factor is the central limit theorem, which implies that the loglikelihood will be approximately quadratic near the true parameter values, so that starting Newton-type approximation at a good starting value is enough.  So, you can actually get a long way without doing any formal checking.  Another reason is just bias: people prefer to use nicely-behaved models even when they aren't realistic.
And finally, in problems where there is a genuine risk of ending up at a stationary point that isn't the global maximum, that stationary point is often a local maximum, not a saddlepoint or minimum. In these cases, second-derivative and boundary checks won't get you any further forward. These problems get handled by trying to find good starting values, or trying a lot of starting values, or using something like simulated annealing, or giving up on maximisation and using Bayesian inference via MCMC.

All good points. With regard to your last paragraph -- unfortunately many standard MCMC samplers also work poorly on multimodal posterior surfaces ...

Absolutely. Nothing really works well, but averaging has a bit more of a chance than maximisation

Not sure if I'm misremembering, but is there a theorem that says you don't need to check the second derivative or the boundaries if we're working with the exponential family?

@NoppaweeApichonpongpan I think that the point is that you have to check if you have a bounded support

I think one additional point given the context of "professors and textbooks" is that solving the equation is considered more beneficial for learning, in addition to knowing that you might need to check the borders, that the point is not a local maximum etc. They focus on the interesting or more relevant part of the problem. In real world modeling you would still need to do those checks, if it is possible for the MLE to be found elsewhere.

Great answer @ThomasLumley but I really don't think that this statement is correct "the central limit theorem implies that the loglikelihood will be approximately quadratic near the true parameter values". In my opinion, Local Asymptotic Normality is a separate topic that we need to separate from other asymptotic results. Also, if we're going to link it to another theorem, we should focus on the law-of-large numbers instead (saying: empirical second derivative converges to expected one), but even that is tricky since it would not work in cases in which each summand is only once-differentiable.
